# Haskell hClose blocking

Tags: haskell

I am writing a Server in Haskell and I would like to explicitly close a clients Handle after they disconnect. When I call `hClose`, the thread will block until the Client closes their side of the handle. Is there a way to make it close without blocking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Launch it asynchronously? Check out http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/async/2.0.1.4/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-Async.html

Comment: I'd suggest to use some high level library such as [conduits](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit). It will handle all this low-level stuff for you and you can focus on implementing the actual application logic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, just run it in another thread:

```
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)

forkIO (hClose handle)
```

As jozefg has stated, you can use fancier solutions such as those found in `async`, but I don't see a reason to in this case.

Comment: This doesn't, of course, unblock any threads blocked on reading from the relevant handle. A solution that does properly unblock readers is to use the functions for reading from sockets in Network.Socket, but that has headaches of its own... Funny how the self-described low level interface works properly with threads but the higher-level one doesn't...